# How to reference a variable outside of scope in C#

Tags: c#, variables, if-statement, scope

My professor asked us to create a program that takes in a user's height and weight, and then calculate bmi.  I decided to take it a little further and added in some "input validation" logic. This means that if someone inputs "cat" for their weight, it let the user know that "cat" is not a valid weight.

```
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main ()
    {
        float userWeight;
        float userHeight;           
        bool weight = true;
        Console.Write ("Weight:  ");
        while (weight) 
        {               
            var inputWeight = (Console.ReadLine ());
            if (!float.TryParse (inputWeight, out userWeight)) {
                Console.WriteLine ("Invalid input");
                Console.Write ("Please try again: ");
            } 
            else 
            {
                weight = false;
            }
        }
        bool height = true;
        Console.Write ("Height:  ");
        while (height) 
        {
            var inputHeight = (Console.ReadLine ());
            if (!float.TryParse (inputHeight, out userHeight)) {
                Console.WriteLine ("Invalid input");
                Console.Write ("Please try again: ");
            } 
            else 
            {
                height = false;
            }
        }
        float bmiHeight = userHeight * userHeight; // error for userHeight
        float bmi = userWeight / bmiHeight * 703;  // error for userWeight
        Console.WriteLine ("You BMI is " + bmi);
    }           
}
```

The error I get is "use of unassigned local variable..". I know that I am assigning the user variables within IF statements, and that they only persist until the end of that IF statement.

My question is, how do I assign a variable in an if statement, and then reference the new value of that variable outside of that statement?

Certainly I don't have to nest them all, because that seems tedious....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that there is a chance that your variables `userHeight` and `userWeight` are still holding garbage value since you did not initialize them.

You can try initializing them with a default valid:

```
float userHeight = DEFAULT_HEIGHT;
float userWeight = DEFAULT_WEIGHT;
```

Comment: This is false statement if you actually look at the code. While good suggestion to initialize value in this particular case it is not necessary as there are better ways to express the same intent with different code.

Comment: Yup it is true that based upon the code the variables will be eventually initialized but the compiler is not smart enough to realize that. And yes it is true that there are better ways of writing such code

Comment: Setting my userWeight and userHeight variables to 0 worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
public void heightAndWeight()
    {
        double height = getValue("What is your height in inches?",36,80);
        double weight = getValue("What is your weight in kilograms?",45,135);
        if (height > 0 && weight > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("your BMI is " + (height * weight).ToString("N2"));
        }
    }
    private double getValue(string question,int lowRange,int highRange) {
        double ret = 0;
        while(ret==0){
            Console.WriteLine(question);
            string retStr = Console.ReadLine();
            if(double.TryParse(retStr,out ret))
            {
                if(ret<lowRange||ret>highRange){
                   Console.WriteLine("You must enter a value between "+lowRange.ToString()+" and "+highRange.ToString()+". Please try again.");
                   ret=0;
                 }else{
                    return ret;
                 }
            }else{
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid entry. Please try again");
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: Nice refactoring. Also I would not recommend using 0 as special "not assigned" value. Original code in the question had better way to express that with separate Boolean variable. You can use nullable value if you want to keep single variable to hold value and "no value yet".

Comment: no need for extra variable. just use `while (true)` and `return` when the value is valid.

Answer (score 0):

`Do ... while(condition)` is more suitable for your case and also allows compiler to confirm that value is actually assigned:

```
    var isHeightValid = false;
    do 
    {
        var inputHeight = (Console.ReadLine ());
        if (!float.TryParse (inputHeight, out userHeight)) {
            Console.WriteLine ("Invalid input");
            Console.Write ("Please try again: ");
        } 
        else 
        {
            isHeightValid = false;
        }
    }
    while (!isHeightValid);
```

Why: compiler is not smart enough to figure out that first iteration of `while(condition)` for general case will be always executed, so it assumes that code inside `while` may not run and hence variables will not be assigner. Yes, in your particular case it actually possible to detect that first iteration runs, but likely this is not common enough case to add rule to compiler.

`do ... while` on other hand guarantees that at least one iteration happens and hence variable assignment (via `out` parameter) will always happen from compiler's point of view.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you want to initialize the variables with some, for example, negative value; Your code is not going to reach the end until valid values are inserted by user anyway

Answer (score 0):

Fulfilling your request would defeat the purpose of local scope. It cannot be done for good reason. The point of declaring a variable locally is to not litter the broader scope with noise. In your case it isn't noise, your userWidth and userHeight variables have meaning in the main scope because you use them there. So you either initialize them properly up in the method or you declare them inside the if and move the code that uses them into the if section as well. The latter would mean you have some double code, you can fix that by moving the calculation of the BMI to a separate method and call that from within both if sections, passing your variables as arguments and getting back the BMI.

It would not be nice to put the calculation and the output statement in the same method. But that's another story.